# Module "QMLTermWidget" is not installed error when trying to install Termoid Plasmoid

Tags: arch-linux, kde, plasma

I'm running KDE Plasma on Arch Linux. I just tried dragging the [Termoid](https://bhskr.com/termoid/) plasmoid to my desktop but got this error: `file:///home/mycomputer/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/com.koldbyte.kde.termoid/contents/ui/main.qml:28:1: module "QMLTermWidget" is not installed`

Even after installing package `qmltermwidget` I get the error.  https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/qmltermwidget/

Answer (score 1):

I made it work in Ubuntu, but after installing required package you need to logout and login (restart KDE Plasma). In Ubuntu, required packages are installed with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vantuz/cool-retro-term
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cool-retro-term
```

For Arch it is:

```
sudo pacman -U https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/q/qmltermwidget/qmltermwidget-0.1.0-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a maintained and Qml ported fork on GitHub:
https://github.com/Swordfish90/qmltermwidget

after I installed it, I now have a new issue of now 'icon' in systray, just a long text string. But, clicking 'text' does launch konsole.
i'll work on it when i have a minute, having other issues with dup to Leap 15.5 from 15.4... it's Never easy... always issues.

fyi, i did a cursory check and it's Not installed in /usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/ so, i will have to 'find', again, when i get a minute.

couldn't let it go...
it's in /usr/lib64/qt5/qml/QMLTermWidget/

turns out this fork does Not 'launch' a konsole window, but IS a terminal widget/plasmoid and the 'text' i was seeing in the taskbar was the 'terminal prompt'.
this is Not useful to me. So i'm going with plasmoid konsole which lists konsole profiles and a click launches one.
Sorry I couldn't be more help.
Landis.